# What is the CSS selector for selecting the first immediate child of an element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example, if I want the first `<div>` inside a `<p>` element, which selector would I use?

To get all `<div>`s in a `<p>` element, I would do:

```
p > div
```

in CSS.

How could I accomplish this, only getting the first `<div>`?

Comment: Well, you want the `first-child`, why not try the `:first-child` pseudo element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: Smart! I'll go on that route. @Cristy

Comment: FYI: A `p` can not contain `div`, that would be invalid HTML.

Comment: You want the selector documented in the tutorial you didn't bother to read.

Comment: I missed it, am I not allowed to make mistakes? @torazaburo

Comment: It's not about you being "allowed" or "not allowed" to do anything. If you missed this part of the tutorial, then you could also have googled for "CSS first child", or for the exact title of your question if you prefer. This was just a friendly suggestion for avoiding getting down-voted and having your questions closed, by doing a bit of research first before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :first-child selector allows you to target the first element immediately inside another element.

```
<p>
  <div>First child...</div>
  <div>Second...</div>
  <div>Third...</div>
  <div>Fourth...</div>
</p>
```

In CSS:

```
p > div:first-child {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

**Edit**: Important note is that you should never use `div` inside `p`. I wrote this code to show you how to select first child in your case, but it's really so bad to use `div` inside `p`. Whenever you use `<div>` between `<p>` and `</p>` like (for example) this:

```
<p> <div></div> </p>
```

Browser will attempt to correct (to be valid code) it to this:

```
<p></p> <div></div> <p></p>
```

**Good luck!**

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will choose that route.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `p > div` as the tags then the selector would be `p > div:first-child`

It finds p tag then the very first div.

Comment: Why did this get a negative vote? The answer is correct.